What does this functional test include?
Does the test test/functional/test_runner.py include all possible functional tests, or is it just a dummy initial test run?

You can run functional tests individually or you can run the test runner which will run all the functional tests.
From Jon Atack's doc on how to compile Bitcoin Core and run the tests:

test/functional/test_runner.py to run the standard test suite (try test/functional/test_runner.py -j 60 or a similar high number to run the tests more quickly in parallel)
test/functional/.py to run an individual test file
test/functional/test_runner.py --extended to run the extended test suite
test/functional/test_runner.py --help to see the various options for running tests


When should functional tests be run? Is it after changing a particular piece of code, or is always a good time to run functional tests?
